# Simple Rating system in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I created this code to Show the Current Rating of a product using stars.

The number of stars to be displayed will be determined by the results we get when we divide the review points by 2.

*For example:*

Product Shoe has a review points of 4 that means 4/2 =2 (2 stars)
or lets say 6 points 6/2 = 3 (3 stars).
Since the maximum number of stars is 5.
If the results we get when we divide points is greater than 5 the stars will stay at 5.

Here is my example code,  but it's not working correctly and it's confusing.

```
$star = "<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-star' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></li>";
$total_stars = $product_review / 2;

for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    if($product_review >= $i) {
        if($total_stars) {
            echo $star; 
        }                                           
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't say what your problem is.

Comment: `for ($i = 2; $i <= $product_review; $i += 2) echo $star;`

Comment: `echo str_repeat($star, min(ceil($product_review / 2), 5));`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to still use your code above, Here is the fixed code.

```
<?php 

    $star = "<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-star' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></li>";
    $total_stars = (int)($product_review / 2);

    for ($i=0; $i < $total_stars ; $i++) {
        if ($i === 5) {
            break;
        }else{
            echo $star;
        }
    }
?>
```